# How to create Institutions and assign user to particular Company/Institution or private

Tags: moodle, roles, assign

How to create Different Institutions / Company in moodle,
And Create Users to that particular Institutions / Company.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to multitenant support in Moodle, there is no 'perfect' solution, but there are a number of approaches that you could take.

See https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Multitenant_support or http://www.synergy-learning.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/Multi-tenancy-in-Moodle.pdf for some ideas about how to do this.

You may also find some of the features you need in [Iomad](http://www.iomad.org/what-is-iomad/) or in [Totara](http://www.totaralms.com/).